# Mocking GetItemLinqQueryable and Extension method ToFeedIterator()

Tags: c#, moq, azure-cosmosdb

We are using Azure cosmos client V3.
For fetching data we are using GetItemLinqQueryable and ToFeedIterator for making it Async. It works well however while mocking/unit testing we are getting error related to ToFeedIterator

Code:

```
IOrderedQueryable<T> linqQueryable = _container.GetItemLinqQueryable<T>(requestOptions: requestOptions);
var feedIterator = linqQueryable.Where(predicate).ToFeedIterator();
```

For mocking 
UnitTestCode Code:

```
var _mockResponse = new Mock<ItemResponse<Test>>();
mockContainer.Setup(x => x.GetItemLinqQueryable<Test>(It.IsAny<bool>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<QueryRequestOptions>())).Returns(queryable);
```

It does return 1 records from GetItemLinqQueryable however ToFeedIterator() fails saying **System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'ToFeedIterator is only supported on cosmos LINQ query operations
Parameter name: linqQuery'**

Answer (score 6):

I ran into this same issue. Check out the comments in this github issue [893](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/issues/893#issuecomment-560809045) in the azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3 repo. I ended up following approach suggested here.

Comment: Since you clearly link to the issue, I would say that you also could include the actual code in your answer. Having a complete answer is almost always better (since links can change and other content may be removed).

Answer (score 0):

I too recently had some Cosmos tests I needed working. I followed the linked approach in Scott's answer and came up with the following:
ICosmosLinqQuery.cs

```
public interface ICosmosLinqQuery
{
    FeedIterator<T> GetFeedIterator<T>(IQueryable<T> query);
}
```

Real implementation of CosmosLinqQuery:

```
public class CosmosLinqQuery : ICosmosLinqQuery
{
    public FeedIterator<T> GetFeedIterator<T>(IQueryable<T> query)
    {
        return query.ToFeedIterator();
    }
}
```

Example fake implementation with Moq:

```
var documents = new List<MyDocument>() { myDocument };

var mockFeedResponse = new Mock<FeedResponse<MyDocument>>();
mockFeedResponse.Setup(x => x.GetEnumerator())
                .Returns(documents.GetEnumerator());

var mockFeedIterator = new Mock<FeedIterator<MyDocument>>();
mockFeedIterator.SetupSequence(m => m.HasMoreResults).Returns(true).Returns(false);
mockFeedIterator.Setup(m => m.ReadNextAsync(CancellationToken.None)).ReturnsAsync(mockFeedResponse.Object);

var mockCosmosLinqQuery = new Mock<ICosmosLinqQuery>();
mockCosmosLinqQuery.Setup(x => x.GetFeedIterator(query))
                   .Returns(mockFeedIterator.Object);
```

The key to `ICosmosLinqQuery` is being able to substitute the implementation during testing and inject a real implementation within your application's services.
Registering your real implementation:

```
services.AddTransient<ICosmosLinqQuery, CosmosLinqQuery>();
```